# In greenplum database, can we Dump Table from query condition

Tags: database, database-administration, greenplum

I am using Greenplum database. Is it possible to take dump of data from the table by using the where clause in gpbackup utility or some method. Because I do not want to export the whole data but only the part of it

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a utility called minirepro --
Provided with a query, it will dump the DDL and statistics of all the tables involved.

https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-Collect-DDL-and-Statistics-Information-Using-the-Minirepro-Utility

Answer (score 1):

gpbackup supports table level backup. What you request is actually not "backup" but dump.  You can use PXF with external writable table to export data to s3, Hadoop, hive, Jdbc targets and others.For example,

> > create writable external table ext_to_s3(like internal_table) location('pxf://aws-s3-gpdb-dump?profile=s3') format 'csv';
> >
> > insert into ext_to_s3 select * from internal_table where a>100;